# regex match end of string XOR next match

Tags: regex

```
^(birthday|weight)(|\s?(asc|desc))?$
```

I want to prevent superfluous spaces if `asc` or `desc` is not specified. ie `birthday` with a trailing space should not be matched. This expression works, but I'm wondering if its the best way to enforce that, having an empty left side in the `(|\\s?(asc|desc))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty side does nothing, since you have a `?` after the group. This one is enough:

```
^(birthday|weight)(\s?(asc|desc))?$
```